# How do I speed up (or break up) this MySQL query?

Tags: python, mysql, numpy

I'm building a video recommendation site (think pandora for music videos) in python and MySQL.  I have three tables in my db:

**video** - a table of of the videos.  Data doesn't change.  Columns are:

```
CREATE TABLE `video` (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    website_id smallint(3) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
    rating_global varchar(128) DEFAULT '0',
    title varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
    thumb_url text,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `websites` (`website_id`),
KEY `id` (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=49362 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**video_tag** - a table of the tags (attributes) associated with each video. Doesn't change.

```
CREATE TABLE `video_tag` (
    id int(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    video_id mediumint(7) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
    tag_id mediumint(7) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `video_id` (`video_id`),
KEY `tag_id` (`tag_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=562456 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**user_rating** - a table of good or bad ratings that the user has given each tag. Data always changing.

```
CREATE TABLE `user_rating` (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id smallint(3) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
    tag_id int(5) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
    tag_rating float(10,5) DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `video` (`tag_id`),
KEY `user_id` (`user_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=447 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Based on the user's preferences, I want to score each unwatched video, and try and predict what they will like best.  This has resulted in the following massive query, which takes about 2 seconds to complete for 50,000 videos:

```
SELECT video_tag.video_id, 
       (sum(user_rating.tag_rating) * video.rating_global) as score 

FROM video_tag 
JOIN user_rating ON user_rating.tag_id = video_tag.tag_id
JOIN video ON video.id = video_tag.video_id 

WHERE user_rating.user_id = 1 AND video.website_id = 2 
AND rating_global > 0 AND video_id NOT IN (1,2,3) GROUP BY video_id 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 20
```

I desperately need to make this more efficient, so I'm just looking for advice as to what the best direction is.  Some ideas I've considered:

a) Rework my db table structure (not sure how)

b) Offload more of the grouping and aggregation into Python (haven't figured out a way to join three tables that is actually faster)

c) Store the non-changing tables in memory to try and speed computation time (earlier tinkering hasn't yielded any gains yet..)

How would you recommend making this more efficient?

Thanks you!!

--

Per request in the comments, EXPLAIN SELECT.. shows:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  user_rating ref      video,user_id  user_id 3   const   88  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  video_tag   ref      video_id,tag_id    tag_id  4   db.user_rating.tag_id   92  Using where
1   SIMPLE  video       eq_ref  PRIMARY,websites,id PRIMARY 4   db.video_tag.video_id   1   Using where
```

Comment: You don't even enclose your table structure, how would you expect something from the community?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I did not want to overwhelm with information, but based on your feedback I've added the table structures.

Comment: This is no much helpful too, you should include the proper schema, because the schema will include data type + index type/column

Comment: Is the more along the lines of what you had in mind?

Comment: One more, include your explain execution plan (The purpose of asking to enclose everything is help people to understand your problem, is for your benefits)

Comment: Thanks, but would you mind elaborating? I don't know what you mean by execution plan.

Comment: xplain execution plan=`EXPLAIN SELECT ...`; (Refer here - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html). Happy asking! (And please enclose as much information as possible when you making next question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Change the field type of the *rating_global* to a numeric type (either float or integer), no need for it to be varchar. Personally I would change all rating fields to integer, I find no need for them to be float.
- Drop the KEY on `id`, PRIMARY KEY is already indexed.
  video.id,rating_global,website_id
- Watch the integer length for your references (e.g. video_id -> video.id) you may run out of numbers. These sizes should be the same.

I suggest the following 2-step solution to replace your query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE rating_stats ENGINE=MEMORY
SELECT video_id, SUM(tag_rating) AS tag_rating_sum 
FROM user_rating ur JOIN video_tag vt ON vt.id = ur.tag_id AND ur.user_id=1
GROUP BY video_id ORDER BY NULL

SELECT v.id, tag_rating_sum*rating_global AS score FROM video v 
JOIN rating_stats rs ON rs.video_id = v.id 
WHERE v.website_id=2 AND v.rating_global > 0 AND v.id NOT IN (1,2,3)
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 20
```

For the latter query to perform really fast, you could incorporate in your PRIMARY KEY in the *video* table fields website_id and rating_global  (perhaps only website_id is enough though).

You can also use another table with these statistics and precalculate dynamically based on user login/action frequency. I am guessing you can show the cached data instead of showing live results, there shouldn't be much difference.

Comment: Thanks - your query achieved speed gains of about 30%!  I realize that I probably need to get this down further before it could live in production however.  I notice that about 85% of the query time is spent in the first query (CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE..), so if you have any additional recommendations there I would be grateful.

Comment: Also, I'm trying to avoid cacheing so that the user's latest vote can be incorporated into the recommendation.

Comment: Nice! You can do another change to speed up things. Drop the *user_rating.id* column and convert the *user_id* and *tag_id* columns into a PRIMARY KEY for that table, because these 2 fields are a unique combination in the table. ALTER TABLE `user_rating` ADD PRIMARY KEY(`tag_id`,`user_id`) .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - that helped a little, but will probably help even more as user_rating grows.  I tried to take that same suggestion[1] and apply it to the gargantuan video_tag table, but somehow it  actually increased the query time!  Any idea why that would be?  ([1] Remove the unique ID column and add a joint primary key on video_id and tag_id)

Comment: Hmm, I can't explain it, but I just tried it again (removing ID column, +primary key on video_id and tag_id, +indexes on tag_id and video_id).  The combined speed gains are substantial.. 65% since my first post!  Thanks!!